# How to remove page number from certain pages in MS word

Tags: ms-word

I have to remove the numbering on the front page and table of content of my project but whenever I change something it changes the whole numbering of the document. It would be really helpful if anyone could help tell me how to edit numbering on certain pages or even remove footers on those pages that would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you be more specific? And this seems to be a non-programming problem.

Comment: See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm. This is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.